# How can I catch an exception that occurs in Tasks when using Task.WhenAll()?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I tried putting the try catch around the Task.WhenAll(tasks) but it did not catch anything.  In one of my tasks I tried to artificially generate an exception by using Substring on an empty string.  But all that happens is the app crashes and defaults to Application_UnhandledException.

```
    private async void RunTasks()
    {

        tasks[0] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www....");

        tasks[1] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www.....");

        tasks[2] = GeoLocate.OneShotGeoLocate();

        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {

            App.ViewModel.ErrorMessage = ae.Message;

        }

 }
```

Comment: You should never use `async void` unless this is a event handler, is `RunTasks` a event handler? If it is not a event handler it should be `async Task` instead.

Comment: Is it a timing issue?  (i.e.) Are you throwing the exception before the code has a chance to get to the try block?  Try moving the `try` block outside the creation of the tasks.

Comment: Did you try catching `Exception` instead of `AggregateException`?

Comment: Oh, it works with Exception! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked thanks to 'nakiya'

```
private async void RunTasks()
{

    tasks[0] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www....");

    tasks[1] = HttpExtensions.GetMyData("http://www.....");

    tasks[2] = GeoLocate.OneShotGeoLocate();

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception ae)
    {

        App.ViewModel.ErrorMessage = ae.Message;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get *all* exceptions thrown from execution of the tasks, use the following:

```
Task taskReturned = Task.WhenAll(taskArray);
try
{
    await taskReturned;
}
catch
{
    throw taskReturned.Exception;
}
```